# JAVA, got wrong value when using LongAdder in multi-thread

Tags: java

I am doing this exercise:

> Generate 1,000 threads, each of which increments a counter
>            100,000 times. Compare the performance of using AtomicLong
>            versus LongAdder.

And the following is my implementation:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.*;

public class AtomicLongVsLongAddr {

    // 9. Generate 1,000 threads, each of which increments a counter
    // 100,000 times. Compare the performance of using AtomicLong
    // versus LongAdder.

    AtomicLong al = new AtomicLong(0);
    LongAdder la = new LongAdder();

    public class AtomicLongThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i ++) {
                al.incrementAndGet();
            }
        }
    }

    public class LongAdderThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i ++) {
                la.increment();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AtomicLongVsLongAddr vs = new AtomicLongVsLongAddr();
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i ++) {
            (vs.new AtomicLongThread()).start();
        }
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.printf("AtomicLong--Number: %s, Time: %d\n", vs.al, endTime - startTime);
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i ++) {
            (vs.new LongAdderThread()).start();
        }
        long res = vs.la.sum();
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.printf("LongAdder--Number: %s, Time: %d\n", res, endTime - startTime);

    }

}
```

I got something like the following as the standard output every time I run this program:

```
AtomicLong--Number: 100000000, Time: 2330
LongAdder--Number: 99882179, Time: 469
```

Apparently I've got a wrong value with LongAdder, but I can not figure out where I did wrong.

Can you help me?

### updated

Under the help of everybody here and @Ravindra Ranwala, I updated my answer for the exercise above:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.*;

public class AtomicLongVsLongAddr {

    // 9. Generate 1,000 threads, each of which increments a counter
    // 100,000 times. Compare the performance of using AtomicLong
    // versus LongAdder.

    AtomicLong al = new AtomicLong(0);
    LongAdder la = new LongAdder();

    public class AtomicLongThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i ++) {
                al.incrementAndGet();
            }
        }
    }

    public class LongAdderThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i ++) {
                la.increment();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            long startTime;
            long endTime;
            AtomicLongVsLongAddr vs = new AtomicLongVsLongAddr();
            Thread[] t = new Thread[1000];
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i ++) {
                t[i] = vs.new AtomicLongThread();
            }
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i ++) {
                t[i].start();
                t[i].join();
            }
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.printf("AtomicLong--Number: %s, Time: %d\n", vs.al, endTime - startTime);
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i ++) {
                t[i] = vs.new LongAdderThread();
            }
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i ++) {
                t[i].start();
                t[i].join();
            }
            long res = vs.la.sum();
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.printf("LongAdder--Number: %s, Time: %d\n", res, endTime - startTime);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If there still are any wrong, please point it out for me. Thanks everyone.

Comment: I guess you're actually timing thread *creation*, not *execution*

Comment: just wanted to say as @Tedil
try to reorder your code what will happen ?

Comment: This is not a good way to write a comparative performance test I suggest you to revise your approach. To know why your test fails see @Ravindra post.

Comment: Thanks. Share I first create 1000 threads and time their running?

Comment: Now you are having a sequential execution. You create 1000 threads. At each iteration you `start` it and call `join` which waits for that thread to die. Then you start the next thread, and do the same. That strategy mimics a sequential execution, not a concurrent one. Check out the solution I have given.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call `Thread.join` on all the threads and wait till all of them are completed. It seems your main thread exits before other threads that increment the two variables completed. What you are getting here is some intermediary result.

Here's the code,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final List<Thread> adderThreads = new ArrayList<>();
    final List<Thread> atomicThreads = new ArrayList<>();
    AtomicLongVsLongAddr vs = new AtomicLongVsLongAddr();
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        final AtomicLongThread atomicThread = vs.new AtomicLongThread();
        atomicThreads.add(atomicThread);
        atomicThread.start();
    }

    for (Thread thread : atomicThreads) {
        thread.join();
    }
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.printf("AtomicLong--Number: %s, Time: %d\n", vs.al, endTime - startTime);
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        final LongAdderThread adderThread = vs.new LongAdderThread();
        adderThreads.add(adderThread);
        adderThread.start();
    }
    for (Thread thread : adderThreads) {
        thread.join();
    }
    long res = vs.la.sum();
    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.printf("LongAdder--Number: %s, Time: %d\n", res, endTime - startTime);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't synchronous - The main thread will exit/proceed before it's finished with the counter threads, thus creating the difference.